# How can Javascript be asynchronous while it is single-threaded?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous

Can anyone explain why we can make asynchronous call in Javascript, meanwhile it is a single-threaded language.

It looks like synchronous/asynchronous has nothing to do with single/multi-threaded.

A good place to study this topic would be very helpful too!

Note: this question only concerns about Javascript running in browser. Javascript running in the server side, such as Node.js could be a very different topic.

Comment: @forgivenson `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are asynchronous client side and has nothing to do with sending a callback to the server... [This blog entry helped me understand it](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Comment: @forgivenson the question is not about "what is asynchronous calling", it is about how the asynchronous calling is implemented under the hood.

Comment: It's just context switching. It's not 100% busy all of the time.

Comment: Finally, I got an answer, please watch this great video:http://vimeo.com/96425312. Basically, Javascript itself is single-threaded, but browser isn't. All the asynchronous calls are handle separately by browser's Web APIs.